# Как узнать, что забивает swap?

Tags: linux, swap

Обычно раздел подкачки пустой и заполняется лишь при работе с очень большими графическими файлами. Но уже второй день творится какой-то непорядок. Можно решить проблему выходом и повторным входом в учётную запись, но мне интересно узнать, что именно забивает swap. Как это узнать?

Кроме браузеров, NetBeans, аудио, видео и виртуальной машины ничего не запускал. Ничего особенного не делал — все как всегда.

Раньше я по две  недели не выходил из системы и все было хорошо.

[image: Экранный снимок htop]

Comment: ух, я и не знал как картинку вставить. Сейчас тоже будет вопрос от меня с картинкой.

Comment: подскажите как загрузить картинку на SO. или такое могут только модераторы\редакторы?

Answer (score 5):

Найдено где-то на просторах и немного допилено под свою среду. Возможно, придётся допиливать тоже, главное - понять принцип:

```
#!/bin/sh
for dir in $(find /proc/ -maxdepth 1 -type d |grep -E "[0-9]+"); do 
  pid=$(echo $dir |cut -d/ -f3)
  cmd=$(ps h -o comm -p $pid)
  swap=$(grep VmSwap $dir/status 2> /dev/null |awk '{print $2}')
  if [ ! -z $swap ] && [ $swap -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "pid: $pid command: $cmd swap: $swap KB"
  fi
done | sort -rnk6 | column -t
```

Comment: я ниже(выше) написал что  и почему произошло.

Comment: "главное - понять принцип:" - та да, но до углубленного изучения как-то руки не доходЮт. %:)

Answer (score 1):

Можно запустить top и нажать f - отобразится список параметров, которые он (top) может выводить. Выбери отображение SWAP - и ты увидишь какие процессы сколько данных там держат. А отсортировать по этой колонке можно нажав F.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get current swap usage for all running processes
# Erik Ljungstrom 27/05/2011
SUM=0
OVERALL=0
for DIR in `find /proc/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | egrep "^/proc/[0-9]"` ; do
    PID=`echo $DIR | cut -d / -f 3`
    PROGNAME=`ps -p $PID -o comm --no-headers`
    for SWAP in `grep Swap $DIR/smaps 2>/dev/null| awk '{ print $2 }'`
    do
            let SUM=$SUM+$SWAP
    done
    echo "PID=$PID - Swap used: $SUM - ($PROGNAME )"
    let OVERALL=$OVERALL+$SUM
    SUM=0

done
echo "Overall swap used: $OVERALL"
```

Найден тут http://northernmost.org/blog/find-out-what-is-using-your-swap/

---

Хочу ответить откуда взялась проблема с swap-space. Это мог бы быть этот баг http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2016-03/msg00360.html , но у меня версия 14.04, так что это не мой случай.

У меня в системе так

```
xuser@mh:~$ df -h
Файл.система   Размер Использовано  Дост Использовано% Cмонтировано в
udev             3,9G         4,0K  3,9G            1% /dev
tmpfs            799M         1,3M  798M            1% /run
/dev/sda2         54G          12G   39G           23% /
none             4,0K            0  4,0K            0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1,0G         183M  842M           18% /tmp
none             5,0M            0  5,0M            0% /run/lock
none             3,9G         1,4M  3,9G            1% /run/shm
none             100M          20K  100M            1% /run/user
tmpfs            1,5G         291M  1,2G           20% /home/xuser/.cache
tmpfs            512M         199M  314M           39% /home/xuser/.mozilla
tmpfs            5,0G            0  5,0G            0% /home/xuser/torTmp
/dev/sdb1        230G         108G  111G           50% /media/xuser/9bd1fae0-bcb9-4677-9f1a-28ac7079dccc
xuser@mh:~$
```

Я запускал виртуальную машину и забыл очистить папку

```
/home/xuser/torTmp
```

а она у меня предназначена для торрентов и образа виртуальной машины.

```
swapoff -a
```

писало ошибку о том что не может распределить память.

Я потом и догадался что нужно глянуть что же у меня в системе с памятью происходит. Конец истории :).